# Applying Style Dynamically To MultiButton LineX Labels

Tags: codenameone

I want to apply RoundBorder style to MultiButton Line2 label when horizontal layout is set to true but calling `mb.setHorizontalLayout(true);` but I can't because LineX labels are not accessible outside the MultiButton.

I know that I can create curved border using theme designer and applying the uiid to the label using any of the setUIIDLineX() method but I don't want to use it because it didn't give me what I want in some device pixel density.

Is there any other way to style MultiButton internal components(Labels) through code?

Again, why is it that LineX labels are not exposed like icon label?

Exposing the LineX labels will equally enable developers to set icons for the individual labels depending on what the developer want to accomplish.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one asked for that so we didn't add such getters. You can file an RFE for that or submit a pull request which will probably be quicker.

Notice you can [style the round border in the current version of the designer](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/round-border-in-the-designer.html) so you can use a the UIID's to set the round border too.

Comment: Thanks Shai, am now using the round border from the designer but I noticed that there is no way to control curves of the border like specifying the arc. For exposing internal labels of MultiButton I will use pull request(though have not tried it before) but if I encounter much challenges I  will file RFE.

Comment: The arc can't be specified by code either since it's always a 180 degree round curve for the **round** border as opposed to the **rounded** border which is something else.

Comment: OK,  what is the alternative to get rounded border without using image border? Like if I have a card layout and want to apply rounded border in code without using image.

Comment: You can use Rounded Border although it's not as savvy as the `RoundBorder`. You can use it in the designer too it's one of the options there.

Comment: Ok Shai, thanks for your responses. I've been using the rounded border in the designer for long now but I thought I could create rounded borders in code with `RoundBorder` because I prefer designing in code. Anyways, thanks once again.